# VB.net - Add IP to textbox

Tags: vb.net

I'm working on a small project to retrieve info from computers and I was trying to figure out on how to retrieve IP info to a textbox. I've tried to call another Sub but it didn't work.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.MouseClick
        TextBox3.Text = SystemInformation.UserName
        TextBox4.Text = My.Computer.Info.OSFullName
        TextBox5.Text = My.Computer.Info.OSVersion
        TextBox6.Text = My.Computer.Info.TotalPhysicalMemory
        TextBox7.Text = SystemInformation.UserDomainName
        TextBox8.Text = 

End Sub
```

I'm a newbie on winforms so don't bash me out :D

Comment: Please read the description of a tag before using it. The VS tag specifically states that it is for questions about the IDE, not about code that just happens to be written in VS.

Comment: You obviously know how to display something in a `TextBox` so that part is irrelevant. Are you asking how to find the IP address of the local machine?

Comment: @jmcilhinney sorry for the wrong tag. What I meant was how does vb retrieves the IP info like the username for example. From what I've seen, I think I have to create another sub or no?

Dim ipEntry As IPHostEntry = Dns.GetHostByName(Environment.MachineName)
        Dim IpAddr As IPAddress() = ipEntry.AddressList
        Dim i As Integer

       
        TextBox1.Text = IpAddr(i).ToString()

Comment: Please don't put long code snippets in comments, especially unformatted. If you think you need to use certain code then use it. If it doesn't work, show us what you did and tell us what happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:-

```
    Public Function GetLocalIP() As String

        Return Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName()).
            FirstOrDefault(Function(ip) ip.AddressFamily = Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork)?.ToString

    End Function
```

The above function should return the IP Address of the local machine.